# Swift compare Int with Int32 or Int64

Tags: swift

I noticed if I use `==` sign on int and int64, there seems no warning and error on that. So does that mean I can use `==` safely to compare with int and int32/64?

I tried this in playground and the result is correct.

[image]

Tried search before asking this question, noticed that most answers are casting from Int to Int64. But no one questioning about if we can use `==` to compare `Int` and `Int64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Comparing Across Integer Types**
>
> You can use relational operators, such as the less-than and equal-to
>   operators (`<` and `==`), to compare instances of different binary integer
>   types. The following example compares instances of the `Int`, `UInt`, and
>   `UInt8` types:
>
> ```
> let x: Int = -23 let y: UInt = 1_000 let z: UInt8 = 23
>
> if x < y {
>     print("\(x) is less than \(y).") } // Prints "-23 is less than 1000."
>
> if z > x {
>     print("\(z) is greater than \(x).") } // Prints "23 is greater than -23."
> ```

From [BinaryInteger - Comparing Across Integer Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/binaryinteger)

You can read [the docs for this particularity overload of `==`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/binaryinteger/2886030), too.